# How is it possible that I can execute JAR file from shell?

Tags: command-line, java, executable

I always thought, only executables in UNIX/Linux are `ELF`-files and shell scripts. But i found that it is possible to use just `$ ./file.jar` instead of `$ java -jar file.jar`.

How are `JAR`-files special? Are there other examples of this behavior? Can I create my own file type that can be executed only by its name/path?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I don't understand your question since in  your title you say "how is it possible..." and then you mention "i found that it is possible...". I don't also understand why do you think that JAR files are special. If so, you think they are different to *what*? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because ubuntu supports the `binfmt_misc` kernel module and the `jar` type is enabled. see `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/jar`

This is very old (since kernel 1.03). See more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667830/running-a-jar-file-without-directly-calling-java

Other examples are python and wine, yes, if you learn how `binfmt_misc` works, you can create your own types too.

Comment: I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04.5 to 22.04.1. While before I was able t directly execute jar file, now I am not. Just because the concept is very old it does not mean it always works.